# Firebase Cloud Firestore get array of maps in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build something in Flutter using Firebase Cloud Firestore as my database. I have a collection ('students') which contains a document of each student.

Within each student document there is an array which contains a map of marks for the student. See below.

[image: Screenshot from Firebase Cloud Firestore document with an array (grades) of maps (various fields relating to the marks a student has received)]

In Flutter I have the following classes:

```
class Student {
  final String name;
  final String subject;
  final List<Mark> marks;

  Student({this.name, this.subject, this.marks});
}

class Mark {
  final int mark;
  final String grade;
  final String markedBy;
  final String feedback;

  Mark({this.mark, this.grade, this.markedBy, this.feedback});
}
```

I'm retrieving the data using a Provider stream as follows:

```
  Stream<List<Student>> get firebaseStudents {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('students').snapshots().map(_firebaseStudentsFromSnapshot);
  }

  List<Student> _firebaseStudentsFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Student(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
        subject: doc.data['subject'] ?? '',

        //trying to figure out how to map the marks!

      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

If I print doc.data['grades'] I can see it is an array of maps with the data in, I'm just not sure how to then map that to a list of the class Mark.

I've looked around and seen suggestions such as using fromMap but can't seem to get it working. I've tried the below (in Mark class):

```
  Mark.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map) : 
    mark = map['mark'], 
    grade = map['grade'],
    markedBy = map['markedBy'],
    feedback = map['feedback'];
```

And in the database retrieve:

```
  marks: List<Mark>.from(doc.data['grades'].map((item) {
    return new Mark(
        mark: item['mark'],
        grade: item['grade'],
        markedBy = item['markedBy'],
        feedback = map['feedback']
       );
     })),
```

But to no avail. I'm sure I'm just missing a key part but I'm still fairly new to this so I'm trying to get my head around all of this.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

**Edit**

Ultimately figured something out that works but always happy to hear if there are better ways of doing this.

I presume there probably is a smarter way of doing it using a fromMap but currently the type differences are causing me a problem but will see if I can get that working as that would be a bit neater.

```
  List<Student> _firebaseStudentsFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      List<Mark> marks = [];
      List<dynamic> markMap = doc.data['grades'];
      markMap.forEach((element) {
        marks.add(new Mark(
            mark = element['mark'], 
            grade = element['grade'],
            markedBy = element['markedBy'],
            feedback = element['feedback'];
        ));
      });
      return Student(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
        subject: doc.data['subject'] ?? '',
        marks: marks,
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem, just post your solution as an answer.  There's no need to edit the question to contain the answer.

Comment: Sorry, still new to this place and wasn't sure if people would have a better solution. Now posted an answer. Cheers for the advice.

Comment: could share the full code if you still have it, especially when you made it more efficent?

Comment: @s3v3ns I don't have it any more I'm afraid. Was just playing around for a long abandoned project sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Ended up finding a solution myself, unsure if its the best but it worked for me.

```
  List<Student> _firebaseStudentsFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      List<Mark> marks = [];
      List<dynamic> markMap = doc.data['grades'];
      markMap.forEach((element) {
        marks.add(new Mark(
            mark = element['mark'], 
            grade = element['grade'],
            markedBy = element['markedBy'],
            feedback = element['feedback'];
        ));
      });
      return Student(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
        subject: doc.data['subject'] ?? '',
        marks: marks,
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Comment: can you please show me how you are adding the marks as an array to each student. I am working on something similar but every time I try to add it creates a new document instead of adding an array.

Comment: This was not something I took forward so can't check the code now but looking at my prev comments; each student is a document and in there is an array of grades. In_firebaseStudentsFromSnapshot I set up an empty marks array and map over the fb array to create a Marks item and add it to the array. I then add this array to the student in the return Student() function.

Comment: Unless perhaps you meant how do I add it to firebase in the first instance? In which case providing you have the link between student and grade already defined you should just be able to use a put command to add the grade to the existing student document. Maybe this will help: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-array-operations

Comment: I know this question is two years old. But while I was searching for a solution, I came across this question. Please check this link regarding my issue. If you can help me solve it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73827518/flutter-adding-and-updating-array-to-cloud-firestore

Comment: I am trying to add grades as well to student document. But When I try to add the grades to same student FB makes another document instead of adding the another array to same document.