# Flutter: Adding and updating array to Cloud Firestore

Tags: arrays, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please help solve this issue. I have a list of records that I want to upload as an array to Cloud Firestore document. On the press of the button the list is getting added as individual documents as an array though. What I want is to be added in a single document as array, everytime I click on add button.

Please see the image below how I am trying to upload data:

[image]

Instead of the above this is how the individual records are getting added:

[image]

This is my toJson map inside my model class:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson(RecordModel records) {
    return {
      'murajaatRecords': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
        {
          'juz': records.juz,
          'surah': records.surah,
          'page': records.page,
          'grade': records.grade,
        }
      ])
    };
  }
```

This is my Firebase Cloud Firestore function to upload data:

```
Future<void> markMurajaat({required RecordModel recordModel}) async {
    final docRef = _firebaseFirestore
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
        .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathMurajaatRDCollection)
        .doc();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      final snapshot = await transaction.get(docRef);
      if (!snapshot.exists) {
        //final updateRecord = snapshot.get(docRef);
        transaction.set(docRef, recordModel.toJson(recordModel));
      } else {
        var docId = docRef.id;
        final newDoc = _firebaseFirestore
            .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
            .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathMurajaatRDCollection)
            .doc(docId);
        transaction.update(newDoc, recordModel.toJson(recordModel));
      }
    }).then((value) => print('Record updated'),
        onError: (e) => print('Error updating record $e'));
  }
```

Inside my controller class I have this method, when user clicks on the button records gets added and then uploads to Cloud Firestore.

```
void markRecord(RecordModel records) async {
    recordModel.add(records);
    final avgValue =
        recordModel.map((element) => element.grade as double).toList();
    averageGrade.value = avgValue.average;
    try {
      await _firestoreFunctions.markMurajaat(recordModel: records);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

My button where from where records are being added:

```
GFButton(
                    color: AppColors.spaceCadet,
                    elevation: Sizes.dimen_6,
                    size: GFSize.MEDIUM,
                    text: 'MARK',
                    fullWidthButton: true,
                    onPressed: () {
                      var muraRecord = RecordModel(
                        juz: controller.juzString.value,
                        surah: controller.surahString.value,
                        page: controller.pageString.value,
                        grade: controller.grade.value,
                      );
                      controller.markRecord(muraRecord);
                      controller.grade.value = 10.0;
                    },
                  ),
```

These are the list of records that I am trying to upload:

[image]

I am not sure what my mistake is here. Why each record is being added as individual document and under a single document. Please help me figure this out. Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!